# Google Apps Script to turn Spreadsheet of options signups into list of signups for each option

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this

```
+------+-----------------------------+
| Col1 |            Col2             |
+------+-----------------------------+
| Joe  | pepperoni, sausage, peppers |
| Bill | pepperoni, onions           |
+------+-----------------------------+
```

I want to turn the spreadsheet into this:

```
Pepperoni: Joe, Bill
Sausage: Joe
Peppers: Joe
Onions: Bill
```

I'm not seeing an easy way to do this in GAS. Is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with a an Object:
`var obj = {};`
Parse each row in a for loop:
`for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) { ....`
for each row take the col2 and split the condiments in an array:
`var condiments = data[i][1].split(",")  // [1] == Col2 index`
loop through each condiment:
`for (var c=0; c<condiments.length; c++) { ....`
Change the `obj` with the condiments **Here is the magic**:
`obj[condiments[c]] = obj[condiments[c]] || []; // vodoo magik`
`obj[condiments[c]].push(data[i][0]); // [0] == Col1 index , standard magik`
Then parse the obj to rebuild a table with it.

The complete script look to something like that:

```
function parsePizzas(){
  var obj = {};
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("A2:B").getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] == "") {
      continue; // skip empty rows
    }
    var condiments = data[i][1];
    condiments = condiments.split(",");
    for (var k = 0;k<condiments.length; k++) {
      obj[condiments[k]] = obj[condiments[k]] || [];
      obj[condiments[k]].push(data[i][0]);
    }
  }
  var out = [];
  for (var o in obj) {
    out.push([o, obj[o]]); // o == object name, obj[o] == objec value
  }
  return out;
}
```